# How to get progress out of an async method that takes an IProgress<T> parameter?

Tags: c#, download

I'm trying to download a file hosted on mega.nz with C#. I'm using [MegaApiClient](https://github.com/gpailler/MegaApiClient), however i can't understand how can i get the download progress with this function:

```
public Task DownloadFileAsync(Uri uri, string outputFile, IProgress<double> progress)
{
  return Task.Run((Action) (() =>
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFile))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("outputFile");
    using (Stream stream = (Stream) new ProgressionStream(this.Download(uri), progress))
      this.SaveStream(stream, outputFile);
  }));
}
```

What i have until now:

```
var client = new MegaApiClient();
        client.LoginAnonymous();
        IProgress<double> ze = null;
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://mega.nz/#!Yo0l2YiQ!hW7Hzqrjlm3-zO31oof_dQ6Wd23YsIT5ZI8v-9Fau2s"), Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ze.rar", ze);
```

How can i retrieve progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and pass in a [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of null. The `Progress<T>` you pass in ultimately is called by the async method to report progress back to you.

A one-line change that prints progress out to the console,

```
Progress<double> ze = new Progress<double>(p => Console.WriteLine($"Progress updated: {p}"); 
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://mega.nz/#!Yo0l2YiQ!hW7Hzqrjlm3-zO31oof_dQ6Wd23YsIT5ZI8v-9Fau2s"), Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\ze.rar", ze);
```

You can also listen to the `Progress<T>.ProgressChanged` event to the same effect.

Comment: It is working, although i had to do new Progress<double>! Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes you did. That's what I get for not making sure my answer compiles. :)